# Problema de types com ProjectionList em criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Estou com um problema no java dando o seguinte erro:

```
in class: com.app.myApp.ReportDTO, setter method of property: indicator
expected type: java.lang.Double, actual value: java.lang.IntegerInteger
```

Que ocorre em meu criteria, ao criar uma *projecitonList*, setando uma *projection* como **SUM**:

```
projectionList.add(Projections.sum(propertyIndicator), "indicator");
```

Ao dar o `criteria.List();` o erro é estourado. O mais estranho é que quando eu utilizava a função avg, ao invés do sum, funcionava normalmente, sem erro.

Pelo que vi, o erro ocorre pq a minha `propertyIndicator` é um **Integer**, e o property `"indicator"` é um **Double**. Consigo realizar a conversão desses properties na função **sum**?

Comment: Quais parametros `projectionList.add` aceita?

Comment: ele aceita diversos parametros, o problema é que o sum vc coloca a string com o nome da propriedade, que essa pode ser qualquer tipo de parametro. Por isso não dava pra fazer uma conversão dentro do sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não foi possível fazer uma conversão explicita dentro do **Projections.sum**, portanto tive que ir em busca de outros recursos, e alterei o setter do meu *DTO* para receber um *Integer* como parametro, e dentro do mesmo fazer a conversão da propriedade para *double*:

```
public void setIndicator(Integer indicator) {
        if (indicator != null) {
            this.indicator = Double.valueOf(indicator.doubleValue());
        } else {
            this.indicator = null;
        }
    }
```